# "Geotag and Import Photos" Paths needed for settings

Tags: qgis, linux, photos

Running linux ementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
        QGIS 2.18.16
trying to use "Geotag and Import Photos" and can not find the path and the .exe path  here is what I have done:

**Download:**
downloaded from here:https://sourceforge.net/projects/exiftool/files/

**Install:**
Unix Platforms
Download the Image-ExifTool distribution from the ExifTool home page 
(The file you download should be named "Image-ExifTool-11.01.tar.gz".)
Unpack the distribution and make it your current directory by typing:

```
cd <your download directory>
gzip -dc Image-ExifTool-11.01.tar.gz | tar -xf -
cd Image-ExifTool-11.01
```

(At this point you may run exiftool by typing "./exiftool ".)
Test and install ExifTool by typing:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make test
sudo make install
```

Atfter adding the plugin "Geotag and Import Photos" I need to add some paths for the exiftool but can not figure out were these are:

[image]

I have installed exiftool at the home directory and it looks like this:

[image]

**ANY help would be great**

Comment: If you want to geotag pictures, you could use [GottenGeography](https://launchpad.net/~gottengeography/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) as an alternative.

Comment: Can you link to a good how to for "Gotten Geography". I cant seem to find much  on the use of it.